# Why is my javafx scrollpane immediately scrolling to the bottom?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

I have a settings panel which is not resizeable that was getting crowded so I decided to add the gridpane which contains the settings to a scrollpane. The issue is that the scrollpane starts at the bottom when the application starts up. The weird thing is that I set the HValue to 0 to it should start at the top. This is a gif showing it in scene builder: https://gyazo.com/f10a1641b8357e4fc30cd180c0425dae
No code is interacting with the scrollpane at all and as you can see the scene builder preview window also has the same issue so it has something to do with the FXML. To reproduce it you can simply setup a javafx project yourself using the fxml shared below, then just run it and see how the scrollbar skips to the bottom.
The full FXML file: https://pastebin.com/aS3Dn3pH.
Snippet of only the scrollpane stuff:

```
 <AnchorPane fx:id="settingsPane" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="381.0" prefWidth="380.0">
    <ImageView layoutX="84.0" layoutY="-28.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@images/up.png" />
    </ImageView>
  <ScrollPane fx:id="settingsScrollPane" hbarPolicy="NEVER" pickOnBounds="false" prefWidth="480.0" stylesheets="@style.css" vvalue="1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <content>
          <GridPane hgap="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" prefWidth="480.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="270.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="270.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
              <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="20.0" />
              </padding>
              <Label text="%no_away" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label alignment="TOP_LEFT" text="%no_away_message" textFill="#f2efef" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label text="%auto_queue" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label text="%auto_queue_message" textFill="#f2efef" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label text="%quick_replies" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label text="%quick_replies_message" textFill="#f2efef" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Separator opacity="0.33" prefHeight="1.0" prefWidth="307.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
              <JFXButton fx:id="craftKeyBtn" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleSettingsButtonPressed" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="180.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1e2328; -fx-border-color: d9ae50;" text="%craft_all_keys" textFill="#d9ae50" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="11" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                  <font>
                      <Font name="System Bold" size="11.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXButton>
              <JFXButton fx:id="disenchantBtn" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleSettingsButtonPressed" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="180.0" ripplerFill="#1986b1" style="-fx-background-color: #1e2328; -fx-border-color: d9ae50;" text="%disenchant_champions" textFill="#d9ae50" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="11" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                  <font>
                      <Font name="System Bold" size="11.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXButton>
              <JFXToggleButton fx:id="noAwayBtn" onAction="#handleToggleButtonPressed" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="120.0" size="11.0" text="On" textFill="#eda678" toggleColor="#eda678" toggleLineColor="#eba478e2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXToggleButton>
              <JFXToggleButton fx:id="autoQueueBtn" onAction="#handleToggleButtonPressed" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="120.0" size="11.0" text="On" textFill="#eda678" toggleColor="#eda678" toggleLineColor="#eba478e2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXToggleButton>
              <JFXToggleButton fx:id="quickReplyBtn" onAction="#handleToggleButtonPressed" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="120.0" size="11.0" text="On" textFill="#eda678" toggleColor="#eda678" toggleLineColor="#eba478e2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXToggleButton>
              <Label text="%autoupdate_state" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <Label text="%autoupdate_message" textFill="#f2efef" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
              <JFXToggleButton fx:id="autoUpdateBtn" onAction="#handleToggleButtonPressed" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="120.0" size="11.0" text="On" textFill="#eda678" toggleColor="#eda678" toggleLineColor="#eba478e2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="13.0" />
                  </font>
              </JFXToggleButton>
           <Label text="%force_english" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="8" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
              <font>
                 <Font size="16.0" />
              </font>
           </Label>
           <Label text="%force_english_message" textFill="#f2efef" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="9" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
              <font>
                 <Font size="13.0" />
              </font>
           </Label>
           <JFXToggleButton fx:id="force_english_btn" onAction="#handleToggleButtonPressed" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="120.0" size="11.0" text="On" textFill="#eda678" toggleColor="#eda678" toggleLineColor="#eba478e2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
              <font>
                 <Font size="13.0" />
              </font>
           </JFXToggleButton>
          </GridPane>
     </content>
  </ScrollPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Added a reproduce step section

Answer (score 0):

Adding `focusTraversable="false"` to every node in the gridpane solved the issue.
The issue was that it was focussing on the button at the bottom on startup thus moving the slider there. This solution simply makes it so that nothing gets randomly focussed without user input anymore.